# Creating a custom issue file with CoreOS

Tags: coreos

I am building a VM with CoreOS and I would like to have a custom message shown before login. I would normally just modify the /etc/issue file to do this, but in CoreOS this file is autogenerated by the issuegen script that is called from a number of places.

I have been able to stop the autogeneration of the issue file by overriding a bunch of default stuff in CoreOS, but I am hoping that there is a way via cloud-config or some other more elegant way to achieve this.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "override a bunch of stuff"? I found your question and you already made it some distance but don't share how you got there. This would be useful to know how to disable.

Comment: More details on 'override a bunch of stuff' for @pwaller:
 1: replace /etc/udev/rules.d/90-issuegen.rules with an empty file;
 2: replace /etc/tmpfiles.d/issuegen.conf with an empty file;
 3: create /etc/systemd/system/issuegen.service to just run /usr/bin/echo (overrides the default one that changed the issue file);
 4: create /etc/systemd/system/ssh-keygen.service to just run the sshd-keygen script;
 5: create /etc/systemd/system/.service to just run /usr/bin/echo;

Like I said, it is not elegant and is quite brittle for future upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for "CoreOS motd" lead me to a "[Tips and other settings](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/other-settings/#adding-custom-messages-to-motd)" page on the CoreOS site.

Long story short, you can set a custom motd file using *cloud-init*:

```
#cloud-config

write_files:
  - path: /etc/motd.d/pi.conf
    content: This machine is dedicated to computing Pi
```

The page covers a lot of other useful things that you could tweak if you needed.

In general I've found the quality of the CoreOS docs very good, just take a cup of coffee and scan through the pages. Later when you need to do something specific, or new, you'll remember that you've probably stumbled onto it in the docs... If nothing else, they are just enlightening and shows you the potential of the platform you're betting on.